# How to increment the number of running threads dynamically and wait for them using a list?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010, waitformultipleobjects

I want to create a list of thread and change the number of running threads each interval of time ( depending on some condition), which is not possible using `array of THandle` because - as you know - here I need to fix the length of the array before creating threads, this is how I proceed:

```
procedure MainThread.execute;
var 
  HandleThread : THandle;
  ListOfThreadsH : TList;
begin
  ListOfThreadsH := TList.create;              
  while (condition) do
  begin
    HandleThread := TMyThread.Create( parameter1,..,parametern).Handle;
    ListOfThreadsH.add (HandleThread);
    ThreadCount := ThreadCount + 1;
  end;
  waitForMultipleObjects(ThreadCount, pointer(ListOfThreadsH), True, INFINITE);
end;
```

But, I'm having some issues with this:

- Incompatible types pointer and cardinal in : `ListOfThreadsH.add (HandleThread);`, I can understand why I'm getting this but don't really know how to solve it.
- Is it correct to wait for threads this way? Because as I know `ListOfThreadsH` type must be `array of THandle`. If not, how to wait for threads in this case?

If this is not the correct way to increment the number of running threads, then how to proceed? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Why do you need to fix the length of an array. You can use a dynamic array. You can use a generic `TList<TThread>` to hold your list of thread objects if you want. You can add and remove from that. You can create a dyn array of thread handles from that quite easily. This isn't really anything to do with threads. You are leaking memory like a sieve.

Comment: You code does need to check the return value of `WaitForMultipleObjects` and also avoid waiting for more than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`, which is 64 IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array of ...` is dynamic, you can change its size at any time, eg:

```
procedure MainThread.execute;
var 
  ListOfThreads : TObjectList;
  ArrOfHandles : array of THandle;
  Thread : TMyThread;
begin
  ListOfThreads := TObjectList.Create(True);
  try
    while (condition) do
    begin
      Thread := TMyThread.Create(...);
      ListOfThreads.Add(Thread);
      SetLength(ArrOfHandles, Length(ArrOfHandles) + 1);
      ArrOfHandles[High(ArrOfHandles)] := Thread.Handle;
    end;
    WaitForMultipleObjects(Length(ArrOfHandles), PWOHandleArray(Pointer(ArrOfHandles)), True, INFINITE);
  finally
    ListOfThreads.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure MainThread.execute;
var 
  ListOfThreads : TObjectList;
  ListOfHandles : TList<THandle>;
  Thread : TMyThread;
begin
  ListOfThreads := TObjectList.Create(True);
  try
    ListOfHandles := TList<THandle>.Create;
    try
      while (condition) do
      begin
        Thread := TMyThread.Create(...);
        ListOfThreads.Add(Thread);
        ListOfHandles.Add(Thread.Handle);
      end;
      WaitForMultipleObjects(ListOfHandles.Count, PWOHandleArray(Pointer(ListOfHandles.ToArray)), True, INFINITE);
    finally
      ListOfHandles.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ListOfThreads.Free;
  end;
end;
```